# Is this a stretched model? texture? im not sure what to call this or how to fix it

Tags: modeling

Im not sure what to call this or how to fix it. Basically, i am trying to prepare a model to import it to VRchat. However, I'm having some issues here. Does anyone know a way to fix this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXhef.jpg

Comment: select this part in Edit mode, go into the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, remove from all groups, and assign them to the right group

Comment: It doesnt show any bone groups

Comment: oh nvm im new to this, tysm